# Exporting and importing a database

Tags: oracle, import, export, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have setup an Oracle 11g Database and have a question about exporting and importing a database.

I am using Enterprise Manager and have browsed to the following: Data Movement->Export to Export Files. Down the bottom of the screen, I need to supply Host Credentials. When trying to use the username SYS, I see that the error message says to logout and login using a different role.

What role should I use? Should I create a specific role for this task, and if so, what priviledges should the role have?

Answer (score 2):

The link below is from oracledistilled.com and goes through Enterprise Manager >> Data Movement.

[Clone a Database to Another Host using Enterprise Manager 11gR1 Grid Control](http://www.oracledistilled.com/oracle-database/administration/clone-a-database-to-another-host-using-enterprise-manager-11gr1-grid-control/)

It is very well explained with good screen shots and walks through Cloning i.e. another function under 'Data Movement' >> 'Export Export to File'.

Under host credentials the normal user is the O/S Oracle user, [Alex Poole](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/847/alex-poole) mentioned in a comment:

> Host credentials are for an operating system account (e.g. Oracle). `SYS` is a database account and has to be connected `AS SYSDBA` (not as 'normal' in the drop-down role when you log in to EM).

Comment: Can anyone Explain why one needs to login as the user SYSTEM and not SYS in order to move data and why one needs to login using default role and not sysdba role